# Print to console using System.out.write

Tags: java

It is homework question.

**Question:**

> > "Use an array of integers with size 10 and print the content of the array using write( ) method.
> >
> > Note: Please do not use System.out.println( ) method."

This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't work.

```
int i = 0;
while (i != array.length) {
  byte[] temp = new byte[4];
  temp[0] = (byte) (array[i] & 256);
  array[i] = array[i] >> 8;
  temp[1] = (byte) (array[i] & 256);
  array[i] = array[i] >> 8;
  temp[2] = (byte) (array[i] & 256);
  array[i] = array[i] >> 8;
  temp[3] = (byte) (array[i] & 256);
  System.out.write(temp, 0, 4);
  i++;
}
```

I can't find a way to do this, please help me out.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks this is WAY overcomplicated given the problem statement?

Comment: What was wrong with revision 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void printInt(int x) {
  String s = String.valueOf(x);
  for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
     System.out.write(s.charAt(i));
  }
  System.out.write('\n');
}
```

Edit: prettier:

```
void printInt(int x) {
  String s = String.valueOf(x);
  System.out.write(s.getBytes());
  System.out.write('\n')
}
```

Comment: The edited one must be like this:- System.out.write(s.getBytes(), 0, s.getBytes().length);

Comment: System.out inherits `public void write(byte b[])` from `FilterOutputStream`, which simply calls the function you mentioned, so it's just semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Have an integer array of size 10, i.e. `int[] i = new int[10]` and write each of them in `System.out.write(int b)` where the `write()` method accept an integer as parameter.

---

**This is really ugly** but it worked....

```
/**
 * 
 */
package testcases;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 *
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] array = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i: array) {
            sb.append(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        try {
            System.out.write(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working:-     
int i = 0;
    while (i != array.length) {
      System.out.write(array[i]);
      i++;
    }

Comment: that won't work! the 'write' method accepting the 'int' argument treats the int as the byte representation. so it's highly unlikely that you'll see any of the int values getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making an array of bytes ? 
There is a write(int b) method.

```
Integer array = new Integer[10];
// populate array with some integers
for (Integer i : array) {
    System.out.write((int)i);
}
```

even the cast (int)i isnt necessary as autoboxing will take care of that.

Comment: Because System.out is a PrintStream any call to System.out.write(int) will convert the int value to an ASCII char.

Comment: Even though this solution seems to have moved up, but this is essentially **wrong**

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to convert each digit of the int into a char. and then write the char using `System.out.write`.
So for example, if one of the int values is 91. You'll need to do

         `System.out.write('9');

         System.out.write('1');

         System.out.flush();`